# Linetypes missing for one group ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
date, name, bin,group, value
2017-08-19,a1,0,1,302
2017-08-19,a3,0,1,35
2017-08-19,a4,0,1,33
2017-08-19,a6,0,1,43
2017-08-19,p1,0,0,76
2017-08-19,i3,0,0,23
2017-08-19,cl,1,1,73
2017-08-19,c,1,0,2
2017-09-19,a1,0,1,302
2017-09-19,a3,0,1,35
2017-09-19,a4,0,1,33
2017-09-19,a6,0,1,43
2017-09-19,p1,0,1,76
2017-09-19,i3,0,1,23
2017-09-19,cl,1,1,73
2017-09-19,c,1,1,2
```

For some reason I am ending up with a plot that does not show linetype for one of the groups.

Here is my code:

```
p <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value,x=date,color=name))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(bin)))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(group)))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))+
  theme_minimal()
p
```

You can see from the image below that one of the linetypes is not showing.

[image]

How do I get that other linetype to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that some lines aren't showing is that for some `name`'s there are two `group`'s. As a result, `ggplot` doesn't which ones to pick for showing the lines and apparently decides to plot nothing at all.

A possible solution is to change the `group`-value to the first one of each `name` and then plot:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(group = first(group)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(bin))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(group))) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

which gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I see. Normally my problem is in the coding not the data. Thanks for spotting the error.